# Swift IF STATEMENT doesn't work in Xcode...What's wrong?

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelSign: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameEnter: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if nameEnter.text == "China" {
            labelSign.text == "A republic"
        } else {
            labelSign.text == "don't know"
        }
    }
}
```

The thing I want to do is when I type "China" in the textfield and press "start"  the information label will change to "A republic". Are there any problems with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the new text in `labelsign.text`, you have to use the assignment operator `=` rather than the equivalence operator `==`. 
Right now, you're just checking that `labelSign.text` is equal to `"A republic"` and leaving that boolean value without doing anything to it.